# Understanding and Resolving Preview Pane Error in Xcode Without Restarting: "Active Scheme Does Not Build This File"

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, xcode-previews

I'm working with an Xcode project downloaded from the official Apple tutorial ["Drawing Paths and Shapes"](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/drawing-paths-and-shapes). I have a feeling the particular project doesn't matter and that this occurs "randomly" but that fact that this is a known-good project is relevant.  Anyways, after navigating to the `Badge.swift` file, the preview pane in Xcode showed an error:

> "Cannot do preview because [..].active scheme does not build this file."

I have verified that the project is unmodified from its original state, so typical solutions assuming project configuration issues don't seem applicable. A commonly suggested workaround is to restart Xcode and reopen the file, and this worked, but I'm looking for a more fundamental understanding of what the error actually means and what causes it and a potential resolution that doesn't involve restarting Xcode since there is no "fix" button next to the error.

Comment: I think this is *just that particular sample*. If you try the [next sample code](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/animating-views-and-transitions) in that tutorial, it works just fine.

Comment: As bizzarre as it is, I dragged the folder named "Complete" (where the `xcodeproj` file is) onto the desktop, and the previews worked there as well. Perhaps the directory name has something to do with it (!?)

Answer (score 1):

I'll fist explain what a *scheme* is.

You can see the currently selected scheme at the top of the window. Here I selected the scheme "Foo"

[image]

The popup that appears when you click on the currently selected scheme shows you all the schemes in your project. Here I only have "Foo".

Different schemes build different *targets*. Targets are the things listed in your project settings here:

[image]

Files can be added to targets on the first tab of the right panel, by checking the checkmarks.

[image]

Here, AnotherView.swift does not belong to "Foo" (in fact it doesn't belong to any target), which the currently selected scheme (also called "Foo") builds. Therefore, when I try to add previews to AnotherView.swift, I get the error of "Cannot build preview because the active scheme does not build this file".

---

That said, the completed sample project [here](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/drawing-paths-and-shapes) clearly has the schemes correctly set up. The previews don't work probably because of an Xcode bug (which it is known to have lots of :D). I moved the "Complete" folder to my Desktop and the preview now works.

Alternatively, you can download the sample code for the [next step](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/animating-views-and-transitions), and open the project in the "StartingPoint" folder. Everything in this folder is completely the same as the things in the "Complete" folder of the previous step.